# C# Async Webrequest

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I need to call a url like the following, programmatically, using C#:

```
http://mysite.com/AdjustSound.php
```

This php file expects a `SoundLevel` from me. So, an example call would be something like that:

```
http://mysite.com/AdjustSound.php?SoundLevel=30
```

I have 2 questions:

### 1:

```
WebRequest request = 
   WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/AdjustSound.php?SoundLevel=30");
// Which one?
// request.Method = "GET";
// request.Method = "POST";
```

**Question 1:** Do I need to make a `GET` or `POST` request?

### 2:

Since, I'm making this http-call very frequently (10-20 times in a sec); I have some speed issues. So, I don't want my program to wait till this http call finishes and retrieves the result. I want that `Webrequest` to run asynchronously.

The other issue is that I don't need to see the results of this http call. I just want to invoke the server side. And even, I don't care if this call finished successfully or not... (If it fails, most probably I will adjust the sound a few milliseconds later. So, I don't care.) I wrote the following code:

```
WebRequest request = 
     WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/AdjustSound.php?SoundLevel=30");
request.Method = "GET";
request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
```

**Question 2 :** Doest it seem ok to run this code? Is that ok to call `request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);` ?

## EDIT

After reading the comments; I modified my code like the following:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Uri temp = new Uri("http://mysite.com/AdjustSound.php?SoundLevel=30");
webClient.UploadStringAsync(temp, "GET", "");
```

Is that ok/better now?

Comment: Unless you can name a reason to use HttpWebRequest, I recommend you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.100).aspx) (<=.NET4.0) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (>=.NET4.5).

Comment: GET or POST depends on the PHP script. If you can open the URL in your web browser without submitting a form, it's a GET.

Comment: It is not ok to call `request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);`. You must call EndGetResponse. Better: use WebClient or HttpClient. Don't forget to dispose objects.

Comment: `I'm making this http-call very frequently (10-20 times in a sec)` - are you sure HTTP is the right way to do this? Is the HTTP server local?

Comment: Can you provide some basic code examples using `WebClient` or `HttpClient` for my case?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Do I need to make a GET or POST request?

A: This example effectively *is* a "GET" request.  Here, I'd use "GET".  If you had a form, I'd instead recommend "POST"

> Q: I'm making this http-call very frequently (10-20 times in a sec); I
>   have some speed issues.

If you happen to have the luxury of using .Net 4.x, I'd strongly recommended looking at their "asynchronous APIs":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I thought `BeginGetResponse()` is an asynchronous call.

Comment: It is.  But really, you're *much* better off using a .Net 4.x "HttpClient", as discussed in the above links.  IMHO...

Comment: Can you provide some basic code examples using HttpClient for my case then?